# Android Multiple radiobuttons get selected after scrolling list. Changes its state

Tags: java, android, listview, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

have listview with each item contains one textview & one radiogroup. Radiogroup contain two radio buttons. My question is when i scroll the listview multiple contact get selected(i.e. as I scroll after selecting some radio buttons, state of radio button changes means checked becomes unchecked) so how should i overcome this. Please do help. I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740614/android-radio-button-in-listview) link.

It has very nicely explained about this issue.

Hope this may helps you... :)

Comment: I have three radio buttons in a row of a ListView. As I select one of the radio buttons from each row of list, and I scroll the list, states of radio buttons changes. This is what actually happens.